# Move out of the current parentheses with the keyboard

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

My TeXstudio (v2.12.4) is very helpful in adding a matching close parenthesis after I type an open parenthesis.

When I type `foo bar (` I get:

[image: bracket]

with the close paren added and the cursor inside the parens.

This is very nice, but it doesn't save me much typing as, to escape the parentheses, I have to type the close paren anyway.

What is the easiest thing I can type which will complete the contents of the parentheses and leave the cursor *after* the close parenthesis?

[image: parens completed]

Comment: You can also type right arrow to escape. Not sure if it is easier, the key is abit further away, but does not need any modifier ... matter of taste and/or  keyboard layout

Comment: @samcarter hmm... arrows are a bit evil in my personal typing workflow. But perhaps there's no other mechanism...

Comment: I think the main benefit of this feature is that you are less likely to forget a closing paren. Especially useful in regards of `[]` and `{}`.

Comment: If there is nothing after closed parenthesis, you can press `end` key to go to end of line. Or you can disable that  feature.

Comment: @LondonRob Can I ask what key you would like to press for TeXstudio to recognize that you have finished typing within the parenthesis, if not the arrow keys or the close bracket?

Comment: @Troy probably tab? Or Escape? Something which is within relatively easy reach of the home keys. Fans of Vim might enjoy Shift+{ but I personally find this a pain to type.

Comment: @LondonRob These two keys have *many* different meanings in different contexts in TXS, I don't see an easy way to implement this for these two keys (via macro). Tab won't be a viable option: how would TXS distinguish btw tabbing the line and escaping the parenthesis? Esc is used to escape autocomplete menu, the search menu, etc.. So it's probably not reasonable to expect TXS to be able to distinguish among all these use cases as well, I think.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>→</kbd> is another way to leave the parenthesis.

Whether this is easier then retyping `)` is a matter of personal taste and/or keyboard layout.